# What is the relationship between inference and decision theory in machine learning?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, inference

I  made a chart to illustrate my understanding of the relationship between inference and decision theory. Could someone point out some mistakes in the figure?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother trying to be "fair" and include both Bayesian and frequentist interpretations. If one is valid, the other one is nonsense. Pick one or the other. My advice, of course, is to pick the Bayesian interpretation.

I would phrase the Bayesian decision theoretic approach somewhat differently. State the goal and work backward from that.

- Goal: compute expected loss for misclassification and choose the class which has least expected loss.
- (expected loss for choosing class k) = (sum over classes j) (cost of choosing class k when real class is class j) times (probability of class j given observables x)
- (misclassification cost) = a matrix such that the diagonal elements are less than the off-diagonal elements, i.e., correct classification has less cost than misclassification
- (probability of class j given x) is computed via generative model or discriminative model
- discriminative model: compute (probability of class j given x) directly
- generative model: compute (probability of x given class j) and (probability of class j), then use Bayes theorem